# How would this relationship be represented?

Tags: sql, database, erd

I'm trying to figure out how to structure this relationship between student, teacher and classroom.

> ***Each teacher has 1 or more students***.

Now considering that,

> **Students have one or more teachers, but all said teachers must teach from the same classroom.**

After tinkering around I have gotten to this stage (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g1Aj.png) , but it feels wrong. Or perhaps instead of linking teacher to room, maybe student to room? I'm not sure.

I'm not sure whether it would also cover the case when for example, you might have 3 teachers (can be more, just an example). Where **"teacher_1"** and **"teacher_2"** teach **"student_1"**, **"teacher_2"** and **"teacher_3"** teach **"student_2"**. Even though they teach from the same room, **"teacher_1"** and **"teacher_3"** aren't sharing students.

EDIT:

> Each student is taught from the one classroom. i.e students can only be taught from one room.

I could have stated that, but that's what I thought was implied.

Comment: What does the dashed line from `teacher` to `classroom` mean? I mean, in what is it different from a solid line? -- EDIT: I get it, the dashed line means FK only (not PFK).

Comment: sounds like homework to me

Comment: "Students have one or more teachers, but all said teachers must teach from the same classroom."
Does that mean that each student has all their classes in the same classroom? Or that each teacher uses only one classroom? I find those texts too confusing.

Comment: @Andrew each student has all their classes in the same classroom.

Comment: @FreshDink, but then why did you associate `Teacher` with only one `Classroom`? The `classroom_id` FK should be in the `Student` table. With your diagram, each teacher could only teach in one classroom.
I just found that in another comment you state *"each teacher can only use 1 classroom (forever)"*, That means all the people can only use one classroom, so all three tables should have a FK to `classroom_id`. I highly doubt that's what you have been asked to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually mostly right in your diagram.  Basically teachers and students are definitely different tables as you have `teacher` and `student`, and they would be linked by a link table called `teacher_student` with dual primary keys off those tables.  In other words, you have what is considered a `many-to-many` relationship, and using a link table is correct.

**One change:**  you have the primary keys set up as `VARCHAR`.  That is a bit odd. I would use `INT` for a primary key for both the `teacher` and `student` tables, and these would typically be set up as `autoincrement`.

It's not entirely clear that you need a separate table for classroom if all teachers teach from the same classroom, however if you mean that each teacher teaches all of his or her individual classes from that classroom, then there's another question.  If there is a `one-to-one` relationship between teacher and classroom, you only need to have classroom set up as an extra key on `teacher` and no need for another table.  In other words, your `classroom` table becomes unnecessary.  If teachers *share* a few classrooms, then you could have a separate table listing the classrooms, and then on `teacher` you would have a foreign key for `classroom_id` which would then link to the controlled table of `classroom`.

**Edit:**
One last clarification.  `Teacher` and `Student` tables are essentially correct.   just change the variable to `INT`.   `teacher_id` is the primary key on `teacher`; `student_id` is the primary key on `student`, and both serve both as foreign keys and dual primary keys on `teacher_student`.

Comment: Yeah, I should have stated that i just used Varchar as a placeholder (disregard the types). Just to clarify, there are many classrooms, each classroom is used by many teachers but each teacher can only use 1 classroom (forever). Now each teacher in their single classroom can have 1 or more students and each student from that one classroom can be taught by multiple teachers.  
  
I was just wondering if my attempt still covers the case (or what I would need to change) so a student couldn't be taught by teachers from DIFFERENT classrooms. http://i.imgur.com/XP6L721.png

Comment: since there is no more information about the classroom (i.e. time, etc),  then just use classroom as an extra field on the teacher table.  From what you have provided, you only need 3 tables, *teacher*, *student*,and *teacher_student*.  If you are satisfied with this answer, please check it as solved.

Comment: If students can only be taught from one room, but have many classes, then just move the classroom field to student.  either way you don't need  a separate table, as this will confuse the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you may want to consider an entity representing a class or course.  One class can have many students.  A teacher can teach many classes.  A room has many classes. This might help resolve your relationships.  (A classroom can only have one class at a time.)
Hope my logic makes sense.